# Solving using the laws of inference.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that the hypotheses
"If I do not fly to Tampa or if I do not fly to Hawaii, then I will walk to school and go to the tennis game",

"If I walk to school then I will go swimming" and

"I went swimming" imply the conclusion: "I flew to tampa."

So far, I've already denoted the statements as follows:

P = I will fly to tampa.

Q = I will fly to Hawaii.

R = I will walk to school.

S = I will go to the tennis game.

T = I will go swimming.

And the hypotheses as written as

(~P $\vee$ ~Q) $\rightarrow$ (S $\wedge$ R)

S $\rightarrow$ T

T

But I don't know how to proceed from here. I've attempted many times but I think the question is either broken or I stumbled somewhere in my understanding of it.

Comment: Which inference rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: Modus Ponens, Tollens, Hypothetical and disjunctive syllogism, addition, conjunction, Simplification, resolution. As far as I know there is no limit really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question seems to depend on the intent of the problem composer.  Two cases below.

$\underline{\text{Case 1: It is possible to go to the tennis game and go swimming}}.$

Then, nothing can be inferred from the premise that you went swimming.  You might or might not have also gone to the tennis game.  Further, you might or might not have also gone to school.  Therefore, you may or may not have also flown to Tampa and Hawaii.

$\underline{\text{Case 2: It is impossible to go to the tennis game and go swimming}}.$

Under Case 2, suppose that you did not fly to Tampa or that you did not fly to Hawaii.  Then you **both**

- walked to school, which implies that you went swimming.
- went to the tennis game, which implies that you did not go swimming.

Thus, in Case 2, the assumption that you did not fly  to Tampa or that you did not fly to Hawaii generates a contradiction.  Therefore, in Case 2, it may be concluded that you did fly to both Tampa and Hawaii.

---

This question represents an anomaly of sorts.

Under Case 1, the assertion can not be proven.  Therefore, I question whether Case 1 represents the intent of the problem composer.

Under Case 2, you do not need the **additional** premise that you went swimming.  The contradiction is generated without this premise.  Therefore, I question whether Case 2 represents the intent of the problem composer.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any Cases other than Case 1 or Case 2.

Perhaps the problem composer is in the wrong line of work.

Comment: I believe its an issue with the composer. I came to similar conclusions that the desired statement could not be proven as there isn't enough information. Even with the latter two hypotheses I couldn't even tell you that S was true.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, this is a broken question.

> "If I walk to school then I will go swimming" and "I went swimming" imply the conclusion: "I flew to tampa."

So that means, if R than T, and if T than P, or **R --> T --> P**.

Transitively, we have **R-->P**

and by contra-positive law, we have **~P-->~R**, or *If I did not fly to Tampa then I did not walk to school*. Depending how you interpret "or" statements this either (a) completely violates the conclusion, or (b) means we need to prove that not flying to Hawaii implies walking to school, which we can't do since there is no data on flying to Hawaii.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).